# How to make break after header in <data:post.snippet> in Blogger

Tags: blogger

I'm trying to make a simple line break between a header `h2` and the first paragraph of a post in a `<data:post.snippet>` in Blogger.

This post kind of helps ([How to increase character lengh in blogger snippet instead of using limited length, 'data:post.snippet'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963026/how-to-increase-character-lengh-in-blogger-snippet-instead-of-using-limited-leng)), but I limited the amount of characters using this javascript code (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bloggerdev/8jUR9uISmA0/J8dmGwACJDgJ) (I don't want to show `<data:post.body>` until the read more tag).

Is there a way to style the snippet to make a line break after a heading?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to utilize the new `snippet` operator introduced with [new themes](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2017/03/share-your-unique-style-with-new.html). It has an option to preserve the line breaks which are present in the actual post content. The code for the same will look like -

```
<b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 450, linebreaks: true})' />
```

This will process the `data:post.body` data tag and extract the first 450 characters from it while preserving the line breaks present in it.

For more detailed documentation of the `snippet` operator -

> #### snippet(string, options)
>
> Produces a short snippet from an HTML string.
>
> **options**: Object specifying the snippeting options, which are:
>
> - **links**: boolean for whether to preserve anchors/links in the snippet.
>   Defaults to true.
> - **linebreaks**: boolean for whether to preserve linebreaks (tags) in the
>   snippet. Defaults to true.
> - **ellipsis**: boolean for whether to append an ellipsis (…) to the end of
>   the snippet. Defaults to true.
> - **length**: Number specifying the maximum length of the snippet.