# How do share full body content

Tags: blogger, whatsapp

```xml
<li class='whatsapp whatsapp-mobile'>
    <a expr:href='"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" + data:post + " | "' class='whatsapp'  rel='nofollow' target='_blank'/>
</li>
```

I tried this by using the above code snippet but it doesn't work.

Instead of `data:post` data tag, I also tried `date:post.body` data tag, but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, the **`snippet`** operator will need to coupled with **`jsonEscaped`** function. Applying this on the *`data:post.body`* data tag will get the full text of the post.

```
snippet(data:post.body,{ ellipsis: false, links: false, linebreaks: false }).jsonEscaped
```

The **`snippet`** operator is used without any *`length`* option to prevent any character limit being applied. Regarding the other options used, refer to [How to increase character lengh in blogger snippet instead of using limited length, 'data:post.snippet'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963026/how-to-increase-character-lengh-in-blogger-snippet-instead-of-using-limited-leng/43091089#43091089)

The complete code will look like -

```xml
<li class='whatsapp whatsapp-mobile'>
  <a expr:href='"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" + snippet(data:post.body,{ ellipsis: false, links: false, linebreaks: false }).jsonEscaped + " | "' class='whatsapp' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'/>
</li>
```

The **`jsonEscaped`** function will cause linebreak character to be replaced by `\n`. Whatsapp doesn't treat `\n` as a new line and will get literally printed as is in the shared text.

Comment: Works Great... Is there anyway to remove that `\n`

Comment: Try something like - `<script>var content = encodeURIComponent(&quot;<b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body,{ ellipsis: false, links: false, linebreaks: false }).jsonEscaped'/>&quot;.replace(&quot;\n&quot;,&quot; %0A &quot;));</script>`
`<a class='whatsapp' onclick='location.href=&quot;https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=&quot; + content' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Share</a>`

Comment: I tried ... But not useful... But I added `%0A` in post body at every line break with white text.