# Blogger custom layout get post initial text

Tags: blogger

I was creating a blogger theme and I intend to have a card layout with the first image and a text-only summary (fixed characters followed by ...) in the post list.

I could get the first image of the post using `data:post.firstImageUrl` attribute. But couldn't find how I can get only a short text out of the post body.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from a related question [How to increase character lengh in blogger snippet instead of using limited length, 'data:post.snippet'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963026/how-to-increase-character-lengh-in-blogger-snippet-instead-of-using-limited-leng).

The issue was solved using `data:post.snippet/` and `data:post.longSnippet/`.

Thanks.